# Request to textfile through $_GET

Tags: php

Currently I can do this

```
<?php 
if($_GET['set'] === "0")
{
file_put_contents('textfile.txt', "0"); 
}
elseif($_GET['set'] === "1")
{
file_put_contents('textfile.txt', "1"); 
}
?>
```

so if I call /?set=1 it would put the letter "1" in the textfile, what I want to be able to do is this;
/?set=anything here 
and it would put what I requested in the textfile, how would I do this?

Comment: Uh, `file_put_contents('textfile.txt', $_GET['set']);` but I'm not sure if you really want that without any authentication that the user is authorized to do that.

Answer (score 0):

write the content of your get variable to your file like this:

```
file_put_contents('textfile.txt', $_GET['set']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `POST` instead of `GET` for that.

Create an HTML form such as

```
<form method="POST">
    <textarea name="value" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Get the value and save it to file in PHP

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST["set"]){
        file_put_contents('textfile.txt', $_POST["set"]); 
    }
?>
```

If you **really** want to use `GET` you can change your code to

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['set']) && !empty($_GET['set']))
    {
        file_put_contents('textfile.txt', $_GET['set']); 
    }
?>
```